# iOS AWS SDK and CloudFront - accessing images

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, amazon-web-services, cloud

Sorry if this sounds alittle confusing (I am trying to get through the CloudFront documentation) but I have an app that is essentially downloading a bunch of images from S3. I tried to setup a new CloudFront distribution, pointed the origin to my S3 bucket and wondering how will this change the way I access my images in my app. The app queries simpleDB to find out what to get and uses S3GetObjectRequest to download the images.

Do I have to use a different path to access images for CloudFront or how does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the cloudfront distribution name instead of the bucket name. Since this is probably a download distribution, the name of the distribution starts typically with a 'd'.
Generally, the full path to a cloudfront distribution looks like this:
http://dxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net

I hope this helps?

Comment: This didnt work for me.
If I replace the bucket name with dXXXX.cloudfront.net it fails to download. Are you sure this is the way to go?

Comment: This is marked as answered, did it work out for you? can you share the solution? I tried using the distribution name as the buckname in my S3GetObjectRequest but I am getting an exception: Message:The specified bucket does not exist

Comment: Did you check if the bucket is public? Standard, buckets are private, therefore you cannot download images unless you make them public.