# Download images through CloudFront (Amazon)

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an app that needs to download some images from S3. I tried to setup a new CloudFront distribution, pointed the origin to my S3 bucket and wondering how will this change the way I access my images in my app. My app just request the images to S3 like that:

```
    S3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:path withBucket:PICTURE_BUCKET];

    S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [self.s3 getObject:getObjectRequest];

    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:getObjectResponse.body];
```

Here, PICTURE_BUCKET is the name of my S3 bucket and path is the name of the image (64758_244.jpg).

**How could I access this image through CloudFront?**

I've found that

> [iOS AWS SDK and CloudFront - accessing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356638/ios-aws-sdk-and-cloudfront-accessing-images)

but I am new with Amazon Mobile Services development and I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using AFNetworking for asynchronous image downloading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is simply how to find the URL to access Cloudfront images, this is one method.

- From cloudfront, check the distribution settings (under the i icon) and note the domain name:
  I have one at: **d3foqimq5fy14v.cloudfront.net** and this is for my **S3 bucket titled panchroma2013**
- **In S3, open the properties pane for an image and copy the link URL**
  I have one at: https://s3.amazonaws.com/panchroma2013/template/panchroma-website-design.png
- While there, **double check file permissions**. You may have to add Grantee: Everyone, yes to Open/Download
- The **cloudfront url** for this image is my **cloudfront domain name + S3 url after the bucket name**, ie:

  http://d3foqimq5fy14v.cloudfront.net/template/panchroma-website-design.png

Hope this does the trick for you!

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response. I have it really clear now. The only thing I don't have clear is now how to access to this image. I just have to create a NSData initialized with contentsOfURL where the URL is that cloudfront url?

Comment: Hi Victor, apps aren't my dept. unfortunately. As a stab in the dark though, is there anything on this page that helps you? http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: That's great ... I'm off to buy some lotto tickets ;)

Comment: I am facing issue to fetch image(private content) from amazon Cloud front in iOS app. I have no idea , How to fetch image/ file from cloud front in iOS . Please suggest it.

Comment: @vipulk617 , I"m not an iOS developer, but maybe you could check  if the accepted answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679544/is-it-impossible-to-use-aws-cloudfront-for-downloading-my-private-image-on-s3 is helpful

Comment: @David Taiaroa  Thanks for giving valuable time for me.