# Using AWS iOS SDK to fetch files from cloudfront distribuition

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using the latest iOS SDK for AWS, and fetching files from S3 works fine using the TransferManager Class

```
S3GetObjectRequest *request = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"test.png" withBucket:@"my_bucket_name"];

S3TransferOperation * op = [self.tm download:request];
```

then I wanted to add Cloudfront for better edge serving, but setting the cloudfront distribution as the S3 bucket does not work..

```
S3GetObjectRequest *request = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"test.png" withBucket:@"dcn1i2k31v14q.cloudfront.net"];

S3TransferOperation * op = [self.tm download:request];
```

it was an accepted answer in this SO question

[iOS AWS SDK and CloudFront - accessing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356638/ios-aws-sdk-and-cloudfront-accessing-images)

I know I can get cloudfront files directly but I wanted to take advantage of the AWS SDK Transfer manager class queue and pause resume capabilities.

any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  The S3TransferManager is intended for use with Amazon S3, not Amazon CloudFront and as such has not been tested or validated for use with this service.

We'll investigate adding this functionality to a later release.  Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: thank you, it is a shame, I hope it will be added sooner than later as I must now add an entire layer of code that does the exactly the same thing with another AWS service..

Comment: That would be great to add support for cloudfront in iOS SDK!

Comment: @Bob is there support for cloud front on TransferManager now??

Comment: @AnilSivadas Unfortunately not. You may want to open an issue on the GitHub repo requesting this feature.